# Execute jar file remotely on Amazon EC2 through AWS toolkit for eclipse

Tags: selenium, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, selenium-grid2

As part of Continuous Integration i want to run my Selenium Test Cases on Amazon EC2 instance through the AWS toolkit for eclipse.
                                                                                  I want to do the following things

- Start 2 Amazon EC2 (Windows server) instances
- Run Selenium grid hub on one instance and the node on other instance
- Run the test cases on the Node
- terminate the instances

So far i have been able to start the instances (i am using an Image which is having java and the different browsers installed) and terminate them. I have kept the selenium server jar a specific location on my instance. I want to access and run the jar on the instances using the AWS toolkit for eclipse.

Kindly help me with this. Please let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

For anything with java:

```
String[] command={"java","-jar","myfile.jar"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Maby it helps?

Comment: i need to connect to the instance first. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.ec2connect.html